# Help me to find lyrics "Couleur Amour" by Jaïa Rose

Tags: lyrics

I learn French and sometimes translate lyrics of the songs I like. I like the song "[Couleur Amour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvu9NOxd2GE)" by Jaïa Rose and would like to translate it, but I can't find the lyrics. I tried to find it in google, apple music and instagram - there is no lyrics.

I hope anyone would help me how to find the lyrics in French.

Comment: you could also post the question in the https://french.stackexchange.com/ forum

Comment: Artist "Aysat" (https://www.youtube.com/c/AYSATLACHAINE/videos) also wrote the song. Perhaps a search using that name will locate some lyrics, 20 minutes of effort from me turned up nothing.

Comment: @Angst thank you for your advice. I did it and people have answered me that it isn't for finding song lyrics 

Comment: ah, sorry about that. In the past, it did help with one other question about a French-language song, at least I think id did.